# JSONException while using Realm

Tags: android, realm

While trying,
**realm.createAllFromJson(MyDetail.class, myJSONArray);**

I received the following message:

**Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value SOS at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

My JSONArray,

```
[
  {
    "nickName": "Tester",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "services": [],
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "id": "1-182P1L0",
        "product": {
          "id": "FA1BF6B0-C8C4-11E5-B42B-0050569C4125",
          "services": [
            "SOS",
            "Call",
            "Text",
            "Mail",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The problem I found is parsing RealmObject without having a key. `"services": ["SOS","Call","Text","Mail",..]`. Realm doesn't support **RealmList**. Can any one give a suggestion to solve it.

Comment: If you have control over the design of the JSON, you can make the services array an array of name value pairs. `{"name": "SOS", ...}`

Comment: This is not supported right now ... Really sorry for that. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575#issuecomment-175206135 for the tracked issue and a possible workaround there. Aslo @AhmedKhalaf would be a good solution for this.